iText 8.0.5 managing french accentuation in Java
I'm using iTextPdf 8.0.5 to generate a PDF.
I have an issue with french characters like é, à, â, ç.
For example the word 'défunt'.
I either get 'dfunt' or 'd©funt' or 'dÃ©funt'
I tried using a standard font, using a local ttf font, using UTF8, using other encoding from this page :
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/latest/com/itextpdf/io/font/PdfEncodings.html
But nothing works.
Here is my code (I removed some content to just keep the cell with accentuation)
import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy; 
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfVersion;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.WriterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder; 


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class EtiquettesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String fontPath = "E:/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/Thanact/calibri.ttf"; 
        
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=etiquettes.pdf");
        
        try {

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream(), new WriterProperties().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0));
//          writer.setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0);

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, "UTF-8");

            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(4)).useAllAvailableWidth(); // 4 colonnes

            Text    label = new Text("Nom défunt : ").setBold();
            Text    value = new Text("MyValue");                    
            cell.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(font).setFontSize(8));
            
            table.addCell(cell);
            
            document.add(table);
            document.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Erreur lors de la génération du PDF : " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

I found some info here :
UTF-8 characters in a pdfcell itext
But it looks like it's from iText 7
Thanks for your help

Web
EtiquettesServlet.java
change
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, "UTF-8");

to
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
....
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

use PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H not UTF-8.
package com.example;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.StandardFonts;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy; 
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfVersion;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.WriterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder; 

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/EtiquettesServlet")
public class EtiquettesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EtiquettesServlet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //String fontPath = "E:/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/Thanact/calibri.ttf"; 
        String fontPath = "fonts/calibri.ttf";
        
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=etiquettes.pdf");
        
        try {

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream(), new WriterProperties().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0));
//          writer.setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0);

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

            PdfFont fontUTF8 = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, "UTF-8");
            PdfFont fontIDENTITY_H = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(4)).useAllAvailableWidth(); // 4 colonnes
            
            String  frenchString = "Nom défunt (é, à, â, ç): ";
            //Text    label = new Text("Nom défunt : ").setBold();
            Text    label = new Text(frenchString);
            Text    labelBold = new Text(frenchString).setBold();
            //Text    value = new Text("MyValue");                    
            //Cell.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(font).setFontSize(8));
            Cell cell = new Cell();            
            //cell.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(8));
            cell.add(new Paragraph().add(label).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(24));
            table.addCell(cell);

            Cell cellBold = new Cell();            
            //cell.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(8));
            cellBold.add(new Paragraph().add(labelBold).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(24));
            table.addCell(cellBold);
            
            Cell cell2 = new Cell();            
            //cell2.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(8));
            cell2.add(new Paragraph().add(label).setFont(fontIDENTITY_H).setFontSize(24));
            table.addCell(cell2);

            Cell cell2Bold = new Cell();            
            //cell2.add(new Paragraph().add(label).add(value).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(8));
            cell2Bold.add(new Paragraph().add(labelBold).setFont(fontIDENTITY_H).setFontSize(24));
            table.addCell(cell2Bold);
            
            document.add(table);
            document.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Erreur lors de la génération du PDF : " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}


Thanact.war - WAR File in Tomcat

apache-tomcat-9.0.96/webapps/Thanact
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── example
    │   │       └── EtiquettesServlet.class
    │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── calibrib.ttf
    │   │   ├── calibrii.ttf
    │   │   ├── calibrili.ttf
    │   │   ├── calibril.ttf
    │   │   ├── calibri.ttf
    │   │   └── calibriz.ttf
    │   └── logback.xml
    ├── lib
    │   ├── barcodes-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── bc-fips-1.0.2.4.jar
    │   ├── bcpkix-fips-1.0.7.jar
    │   ├── bcpkix-jdk18on-1.78.jar
    │   ├── bcprov-jdk18on-1.78.jar
    │   ├── bcutil-jdk18on-1.78.jar
    │   ├── bouncy-castle-adapter-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── bouncy-castle-connector-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── bouncy-castle-fips-adapter-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── commons-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── font-asian-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── forms-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── hyph-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── io-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── kernel-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── layout-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── logback-classic-1.4.5.jar
    │   ├── logback-core-1.4.5.jar
    │   ├── pdfa-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── pdfua-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── sign-8.0.5.jar
    │   ├── slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar
    │   ├── styled-xml-parser-8.0.5.jar
    │   └── svg-8.0.5.jar
    └── web.xml

Test URL:
http://localhost:8080/Thanact/EtiquettesServlet
PDF Result:

Windows Code Page
open CMD.exe or PowerShell ,
run command: chcp
Language:

change
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, "UTF-8");

to
import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
....
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);


My Test Environment

Linux
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
FONT calibri.ttf (Windows 11)

DocumentWithFrench.java
package com.example;

import com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DocumentWithFrench {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //String fontPath = "E:/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/Thanact/calibri.ttf";
        String fontPath = "fonts/calibri.ttf";
        String  frenchString = "Nom défunt (é, à, â, ç): ";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("etiquettes.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        try (Document document = new Document(pdf)) {
            PdfFont fontUTF8      = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, "UTF-8");
            PdfFont fontIDENTITY_H    = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontPath, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
            //Text    label = new Text("Nom défunt : ").setBold();
            //Text    value = new Text("MyValue");
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
                    .add(new Paragraph("Hello 1 >>>> "))
                    .add(new Paragraph(frenchString).setFont(fontUTF8).setFontSize(20) //FAIL
                    .add(new Paragraph("Hello 2 >>>> "))
                    .add(new Paragraph(frenchString).setFont(fontIDENTITY_H).setFontSize(20))
                    );
            document.add(paragraph);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Thanks for your answer but I must be missing something. I still can't get my accentuation :
.
chcp give me 850 but I don't know what it means relatively to the code
I can't paste the code, I only have a few characters to comment but it's your first example

In addition I tried to create a cell for almost each encoding from this page
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/latest/com/itextpdf/io/font/PdfEncodings.html
but I get the same kind of results : (Ã©, Ã, Ã¢,Ã§):

All my files (EtiquettesServlet.java) are archived using UTF-8, not ANSI. The compilation also uses UTF-8.

@Pandalex "I still can't get my accentuation" - the two right cells in you example output look like your Java code files are UTF-8 encoded but your Java compiler assumes them to be Latin-1 encoded. Please check the encoding settings of your tool chain.

I added "-encoding UTF-8" to my javac and got some error on one of my files (the application use 12 files and this was an utility one). I checked and it was ANSI coded !
I changed it to UTF-8, and this time I got the accentuation.
Thank you so much, it was driving me crazy !!!

Because my projects are first developed and tested on Ubuntu (Liunux), and then transplanted to Windows for testing. Therefore, the file encoding of the project at the beginning is UTF-8. I will recompile and execute it on Windows. Except In addition, I use IDE tools to create Java files. I have tested the files created in Windows Eclipse, and the default encoding is UTF-8.
